# Pygame showing surfaces at wrong coordinates with full screen

Tags: python, pygame

So I coded this line for the display surface:

`screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN|pygame.NOFRAME)`

But the thing is, when I place a rectangle at coordinates like (0,0), they are not shown on top left corner, but actually at about the middle of the screen.
Here's my full code:

````
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN|pygame.NOFRAME)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

rect = pygame.image.load('graphics/rect.png')

while True:

    screen.fill("Black")
    screen.blit(rect, (0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```
````

Comment: I tested your code and the rectangle image I have shows at the top-left of the screen. What image do you use, and what is the final result you have?